# How stable is VS2010 beta 2?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, stability

Would you use it to build a project? (C++, in particular)

Is it at all legal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has "go live" license.

http://blogs.msdn.com/jeffbe/archive/2009/10/19/going-live-with-visual-studio-2010-beta-2.aspx

Comment: Where exactly is the "go live" license? Couldn't find it.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It means you are allowed to publish the software you create with it. And that would be the answer to a "what" question, anyway, not a "where" question...

Comment: You allowed to publish software and you have a **support** if anything goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am not commenting about VS2010 per se but in general the Beta tag would cause me to hesitate to depend on it to build a production application. I am sure that it is quite stable and will hardly change before the final release but...there is a chance. The beta is permission for Microsoft to change things if they discover bugs etc.

Is there a particular feature that you require that you cannot do without until the final release? I am a cautious person so maybe its only me. But I usually tend to wait for final release of software before betting my applications on them.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time working with both Beta 1 and Beta 2. Neither me nor my developers experienced any "stability" problems. It does not mean that there aren't any of course.

The reason I did it this early is new and absolutely wonderful editor extensibility model - to do all did (code completion, syntax colorization, etc.) in the old model is prohibitively difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I've been building and shipping a C++ application with a 500,000 line codebase for a couple of months with VC2010 Beta 2. No issues so far, no regression. Pretty good, the intellisense for C++ finally works flawlessley. So I would say, very stable.